# Status from integer to char

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have Status column having an integer datatype in the table "Members". It stores values as '0' and '1'. But on select I want to show "Active" and "In-Active".

How can i do this using Query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Select
    Status,
    case when Status = 1 then 'Active'
         else 'In-Active'
    end as TextStatus
from 
    Members
```

Comment: I cant voteup and i cant vote down .. Repo is still not 15 yet

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CASE [Status]
          WHEN '0' THEN 'Active'
          ELSE 'Not Active'
        END AS MemberStatus
 FROM   member
```

Comment: when 0 it's active? Other way around.